# How to remove document and all embedded documents in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cascade

I have the following schema defined in Mongoose:

```js
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  created: Date,
  photos: Array
});

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

var photoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  filename: String,
  mimetype: String,
  data: Buffer,
  created: Date
});

var Photo = mongoose.model('Photo', photoSchema);
```

If I remove a `Post`, I'd like all the related `Photo`s to be removed as well (like cascading delete in SQL).

If I do `Post.remove({ _id: MY_POST_ID })`, only the `Post` gets removed and I have orphan `Photo`s left in the database.

Also, should I somehow define the post ID in the `Photo` schema?

Comment: Your model is referenced and not embedded so it is not possible to do with a single statement and not even possible to do with two statements unless all your related items contain the parent reference or you are prepared to read the parent and pass in all the `_id` values via `$in`. The only way this can be truly atomic is by actually "embedding" the children in the parent.

Comment: @NeilLunn Can you give me a simple code example? I'm new to MongoDB (hardly a surprise to you) and I'm scratching my head here.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you get a truly atomic operation is to actually use an embedded model like so:

```js
var photoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  filename: String,
  mimetype: String,
  data: Buffer,
  created: Date
});

var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  created: Date,
  photos: [photoSchema]
});

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Then you can actually remove everything with one simple statement since it is all in the same collection and indeed the same document:

```js
Post.remove({ "_id": postId },function(err) {
   // handling in here
});
```

With your current schema you would need to remove all documents individually:

```js
var async = require("async");

var photoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  filename: String,
  mimetype: String,
  data: Buffer,
  created: Date
});

var Photo = mongoose.model('Photo', photoSchema);

var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  created: Date,
  photos: [{ "type": Schema.types.ObjectId, "ref": "Photo" }]
});

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

// later

async.waterfall(
    [
        function(callback) {
            Post.findById(postId,callback);
        },

        function(post,callback) {
            Photo.remove({ "_id": { "$in": post.photos } },function(err) {
               if (err) callback(err);
               callback();
            });
        },

        function(callback) {
            Post.remove(photoId,callback);
        }
    ],
    function(err) {
       if (err); // do something
       // Job done
    }
)
```

If you want to avoid reading the document first then you

```js
var photoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  postId: Schema.types.ObjectId,
  filename: String,
  mimetype: String,
  data: Buffer,
  created: Date
});
```

Then to remove all "photos" related to a "post" then you issue:

```js
Photo.remove({ "postId": postId },function(err) {
   // removed or err
});
```

Generally speaking, if you always want this behavior and your "post" document cannot grow beyond 16MB with all the embedded "photo" information then the embedding option makes the most sense since you then don't require that a "photo" is actually used anywhere else than as a child of a single parent.

Answer (score 0):

If added photos only belong to one `Post`, you can embed all the photos in the `Post` schema. You can do so by pushing photo objects to the photos array in the `Post` schema. Then, your `Post` documents would have the following structure:

```
{
    title: 'My-first-post',
    body: 'Lorem ipsum',
    created: '01-01-1900',
    photos: [
        { filename: 'file1', mimetype: 'type', data: 238947289347239874, created: '01-02-1900' },
        { filename: 'file2', mimetype: 'type', data: 238947284321225671, created: '02-02-1900' }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Would that mean that I don't have a separate `Photo` schema and model at all?

Comment: @VisaKopu Exactly. You simply create the Photo object and push it to the photos array